# mongoDB aggregate find total number of employees group by each state

Tags: database, mongodb

Find total number of employees group by each state using aggregate
I tried the following in the screenshot link below. But the result is 0.

[image]

```
db.research.aggregate({$unwind:'$offices'},{"$match": 
{'offices.country_code':"USA"}},{"$project": {'offices.state_code' : 1}}, 
{"$group" : {"_id":'$of
fices.state_code',"count" : {"$sum":'$number_of_employees'}}})
```

Comment: `$project` stage is the issue, in project you're not projecting the `number_of_employees`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to `$project` `number_of_employees` to count in next stage, or you can remove the `$project` stage

```
db.research.aggregate([
    {$unwind:'$offices'},
    {"$match": {'offices.country_code':"USA"}},
    {"$project": {'offices.state_code' : 1, 'number_of_employees' : 1}}, //project number_of_employees
    {"$group" : {"_id":'$offices.state_code',"count" : {"$sum":'$number_of_employees'}}}
])
```

or

```
db.research.aggregate([
    {$unwind:'$offices'},
    {"$match": {'offices.country_code':"USA"}},
    {"$group" : {"_id":'$offices.state_code',"count" : {"$sum":'$number_of_employees'}}}
])
```